# Codeigniter Active Record return type

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I tried to get a `umat_id` with this SQL query :

```
SELECT umat_id FROM msumat WHERE nama = $nama
```

I converted this SQL query into CI's Active Record :

```
$this->db->select('umat_id');
$terdaftar = $this->db->get_where('msumat', array('nama' => $nama));
```

So this query should return a string (example : "John").

But I got an error when I tried to echo it :
 **Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string**

I have tried something like this : `echo (string)$terdaftar;`, but it's not working.

All I want is to echo "John"

**EDIT** 
Just said I want to insert "John" into a variable. How to do that?

```
$john = ????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As some of the users already pointed the solution, I'm only explaining why you did get this error so you can understand better the querying results that codeigniter gives.

This error:

> But I got an error when I tried to echo it : Object of class
>   CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Happens because you were trying to echo an object.

This piece of code

```
$terdaftar = $this->db->get_where('msumat', array('nama' => $nama));
```

Will return an object, this object will have information about the query you've done.
With this object you can get the result(rows) as objects doing this:

```
$results = $terdaftar->result();
```

Or you if you feel more comfortable with arrays you can return the results(rows) as an array doing this:

```
$results = $terdaftar->result_array();
```

You can also get the number of results doing this:

```
$number_results = $terdaftar->num_rows()
```

And this is just an example you can read more about the results here
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

**EDIT**
A better explanation: imagine that we use the result_array() function to get the result in a pure array format:

```
$results = $terdaftar->result_array();
```

Now your variable $results is an array, to iterate through it and get the data you want you'll do something like this:

```
foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
    //the row variable will have each row of your database returned by your query
    //so if you want to access a field from that row, 
    //let's say for example the name field. You would do something like this
    if($row['name']=='John')
        echo $row['name'];

}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer so you can understand better how you could get a specific field from a row

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$this->db->select('umat_id');
$terdaftar = $this->db->get_where('msumat', array('nama' => $nama));

foreach ($terdaftar->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->umat_id;
}
```

Read the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help :D, please see my edited question (its not in the documentation) :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $this->db->select('umat_id');
 $terdaftar = $this->db->get_where('msumat', array('nama' => $nama));
 $row = $terdaftar->row_array();
 $your_variable = $row['umat_id']; /*Here comes your john*/
```